# How to implement email,call functionality in sencha touch

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a sample sencha touch application trying to implement E-Mail, Call and SMS functionality, but when run the application it's not opening E-Mail window or Call window. Please can I know the right syntax to make it work?

Sample code:

```
Ext.define('Sample.view.ContactsView', {
  extend:'Ext.Panel',
  requires:[
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Text'
  ],

  alias:"widget.contactpage",
  initialize:function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
  },

  config:{
    items:[
      {
        xtype:'titlebar',
        title:'Contact Us'
      },
      {
        xtype:'panel',
        layout:'hbox',

        items:[
          {
            xtype:'button',
            flex:1,
            id:'smsButton',
            handler:function(){
              document.location.href = 'sms:464646'
            }
          },
          {
            xtype:'spacer'
          },
          {
            xtype:'button',
            text: 'Phone',
            id:'callMeButton',
            flex:1,
            handler:function(){
              document.location.href = 'tel:+1-800-555-1234'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        xtype:'button',
        text:'Email',
        id: 'emailButton',
        handler:function(){
          document.location.href = 'mailto:webmaster@example.com'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use window.open() method.

```
window.open('tel:+1-800-555-1234');
window.open('mailto:webmaster@example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, even this works  {

                        xtype:'button',
                        flex: 1,
                        text:'phone',
                        id: 'phoneButton',
                         handler: function () {
                            window.location = 'tel:999999';
                        }

                    }

Comment: @Swar Is there any way to get a call back after call ended. So i can capture the call duration and save it in my Database.

Comment: what if I want to prepare the email content? Is there anything like:  window.open('mailto:frna@exm.com  content: here is the content')

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just using the `<a>` tag

For phone number

```
<a href="tel:+1-800-555-1234">+1-800-555-1234</a>
```

For E-Mail

```
<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">webmaster@example.com</a>
```

Tapping on the link will automatically summon the phone app or e-mail app in both android and iOS.